# gcloud app deploy failed: Docker image not found or not in V2 format

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

Running `gcloud app deploy` exists with the following error:

`Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] Docker image eu.gcr.io/<My Project ID>/appengine/default.20181106t223832:latest was either not found, or is not in Docker V2 format.  Please visit https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/ui`.

Preceding Step #1 was done successfully:

```
$ gcloud app deploy
...
Step #1: yarn install v1.12.1
Step #1: [1/5] Validating package.json...
Step #1: [2/5] Resolving packages...
Step #1: [3/5] Fetching packages...
Step #1: info fsevents@1.1.3: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
Step #1: info "fsevents@1.1.3" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
Step #1: [4/5] Linking dependencies...
Step #1: [5/5] Building fresh packages...
Step #1: success Saved lockfile.
Step #1: Done in 50.02s.
Step #1: Removing intermediate container 0a787554186f
Step #1:  ---> 9032a35b322e
Step #1: Step 5/5 : CMD yarn start
Step #1:  ---> Running in 8f565dd17c36
Step #1: Removing intermediate container 8f565dd17c36
Step #1:  ---> fc272a02adef
Step #1: Successfully built fc272a02adef
Step #1: Successfully tagged eu.gcr.io/<My Project ID>/appengine/default.20181106t225117:latest
Finished Step #1
PUSH
DONE
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Updating service [default] (this may take several minutes)...failed.                                                                                                                                       
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [3] Docker image eu.gcr.io/<My Project ID>/appengine/default.20181106t225117:latest was either not found, or is not in Docker V2 format.  Please visit https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/ui
```

I have deployed this app a month ago without any problems.

```
$ gcloud --version
Google Cloud SDK 224.0.0
bq 2.0.36
core 2018.11.02
gsutil 4.34
```